# (L&L vol. 4, sec. 39) Relativistic Correction to the Wavefunction of an Electron in a Coulomb Field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, special-relativity, atomic-physics, dirac-equation

At the end of section 39 of Quantum Electrodynamics by Landau & Lifshitz there is a problem which obtains the relativistic correction to the wavefunction of an electron in a Coulomb field (in the discrete spectrum).

The problem considers the state of the form
$$ \psi=u\psi_\text{non-r}+\psi^{(1)}, $$
where $u$ is a bispinor of the form $(w,0)$ with $w$ being a spinor describing the polarization of the electron, $\psi_\text{non-r}$ is the non-relativistic wavefunction of the electron, and $\psi^{(1)}$ is the relativistic correction which is first order in terms of $Z\alpha$ ($Z$ being the number of protons in the nucleus and $\alpha$ is the fine-structure constant).

Equation (39.5a) states the Schrodinger's equation to which $\psi_\text{non-r}$ conforms:
$$ \left( \frac{1}{2m}\Delta + \varepsilon_n +\frac{Z\alpha}{r}\right)\psi_\text{non-r}= 0,$$
where $\varepsilon_n$ is the energy eigenvalue of the non-relativistic electron. The text says that plugging the guess for the state into the Dirac equation (equation (39,4)), using the above non-relativistic equation, and omitting terms of the second order in $Z\alpha$ results in
$$\left(\frac{1}{2m}\Delta-|\varepsilon_n|+\frac{Z\alpha}{r}\right)\psi^{(1)} = i\frac{Z\alpha}{2m}\left(\nabla\frac{1}{r}\right)\cdot(\boldsymbol{\alpha}u)\psi_\text{non-r},$$
where $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ is given in terms of the Dirac matrices as $\boldsymbol{\alpha}=\gamma^0\boldsymbol{\gamma}$.
Finally, it is said that
$$\psi^{(1)}=-\frac{i}{2m}\boldsymbol{\alpha}\cdot\nabla u \psi_\text{non-r}$$
solves the above equation.

I do not see how both of the equations above are obtained. Any help is appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Edit: forgot to state that equation (39,4) is
$$ \left(\Delta +p^2+2\varepsilon\frac{Z\alpha}{r}\right)\psi=\left( iZ\alpha\boldsymbol{\alpha}\cdot \left(\nabla \frac{1}{r}\right)-\frac{Z^2\alpha^2}{r^2}\right)\psi, $$
although it is written for the case of a state in the continuous spectrum and where $p$ refers to momentum magnitude of the electron when it is infinitely far from the nucleus. For the case of the discrete spectrum, I believe that $p^2$ should be replaced by $\varepsilon^2-m^2$ (but could be wrong).

Also note that the natural system of units (in which $\hbar=c=1$) is used throughout.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Andrew, I have tried to interpret the equations in various ways, but all to no avail. For example, when I try to obtain an equation relating $\psi^{(1)}$ to $\psi_\text{non-r}$ (by using Schrodinger's equation and dropping higher-order terms of $Z\alpha$, as the text suggests), I obtain
$$ (\Delta+\varepsilon^2-m^2)\psi^{(1)}=(2m\varepsilon+2mZ\alpha/r+\varepsilon^2-m^2+2\varepsilon Z\alpha/r-i\boldsymbol{\alpha}\cdot Z\alpha\hat{r}/r^3)u\psi_\text{non-r},$$
which does not agree with the text.

Comment: @Andrew, also, originally I wasn't able to verify that the solution provided solves the equation at hand, but while trying to type out this comment I figured it out. Nevertheless, while I have your attention, I'd like to ask the following. Looking at the equation relating $\psi^{(1)}$ and $\psi_\text{non-r}$, how does one solve it? If the solution wasn't provided, I'd have been unable to reason through it.